# Is the Basilisk Jaw a Slayer only drop?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

OSRS saw the release of a new quest today and with that comes a new slayer monster called the Basilisk Knight. Their unique drop is the Basilisk Jaw. Can this drop be obtained off task? Or is it one of those drops that can only be obtained on task?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Basilisk Jaw is not a slayer only drop, however, the drop is 5x rarer off-task [according to Mod Ed](https://twitter.com/JagexEd/status/1197864708851810306) (1/1,000 on task, 1/5,000 off task). You can unlock Basilisk tasks with Konar, Duradel, and Nieve with slayer points.